# How to stop auto login after registration in Laravel 8 breeze

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-breeze

Hi I am fairly new to Laravel framework. I am trying to create a separate controller replicating the registeredusercontroller.php in laravel breeze to have a function for admin user to be able to add new users. But I am having trouble with auto login and as soon as I add a new user it automatically logs in to the new user. How can I stop this from happening. I saw posts stating to remove

```
$this->guard()->login($user);
```

but when I see the app/Auth/registeredusercontroller.php I don't see that line.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|string|confirmed|min:8',
    ]);

    Auth::login($user = User::create([
        'name' => $request->name,
        'email' => $request->email,
        'password' => Hash::make($request->password),
    ]));
    $user->attachRole('user');
    event(new Registered($user));

    return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
}
```

how can I stop the auto login after registration.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `Auth::login(....)` is doing the login .... so don't call `Auth::login(...)` then

Comment: @lagbox Thank you :) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this proper way like using custom request handler.
The parameter you need is name, email, password.
So add CreateUserRequest above app/http/request

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CreateUserRequest extends Request
{

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
    'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
    'password' => 'required|string|confirmed|min:8',
        ]; 
    }
}
```

And into your controller just do this;

```
public function store(CreateUserRequest $request) // add your custom request as a parameter

$user = User::create($request)
```

These codes makes your code structure clear and clean.